# True articles list with Google analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working with Google Analytics API and I need to get a list of articles titles. Now I use this to get it:

```
ga:pageTitle
```

But I get some articles with trash titles as well.
How can I get only articles with valid titles?

Comment: The API supports filtering, define `ga:pageTitle!=trash`.

Comment: @Matt, thank you for feedback, do you know how can I determine trash articles?